# Retirar "NaN" de um data.frame no R

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse

Tenho um data.frame com duas colunas que possuem alguns `NaN` e `Inf` e gostaria de substituí-los por `NA`. Estava utilizando esse código, mas não funcionou:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                                        ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
dados <- dados[,-1]

variacaoCasos <- dados %>% 
  mutate(dif_semanal = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(casosAcumulados, 7)),
         percentual_dif = dif_semanal / lag(casosAcumulados, 7)) %>% 
  select("percentual_dif")

variacaoObitos <- dados %>% 
  mutate(dif_semanal = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(obitosAcumulados, 7)),
         percentual_dif = dif_semanal / lag(obitosAcumulados, 7)) %>% 
  select("percentual_dif")

dados <- cbind(dados, variacaoCasos, variacaoObitos)

rm(list = ls(pattern = "variacao"))

names(dados) <- c("estado", "data", "casosNovos", "casosAcumulados", "obitosNovos", 
                  "obitosAcumulados", "variacaoCasos", "VariacaoObitos")

dados$variacaoObitos <- ifelse(dados$variacaoObitos == "NaN", yes = NA, no = dados$variacaoObitos)
dados$variacaoObitos <- ifelse(dados$variacaoObitos == "Inf", yes = NA, no = dados$variacaoObitos)
dados$variacaoCasos <- ifelse(dados$variacaoCasos == "NaN", yes = NA, no = dados$variacaoCasos)
dados$variacaoCasos <- ifelse(dados$variacaoCasos == "Inf", yes = NA, no = dados$variacaoCasos)
```

Mas está retornando o erro `` Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, variacaoObitos, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2295 ``.

Tentei utilizar a função `replace`, porém, sem sucesso.

Base de dados: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está em que a forma de testar para valores especiais como `NaN` e `NA` não é com o operador `==`, mas com funções específicas da família `is`.

Então assim temos o seguinte resultado usando `==`

```
NA == NA
#> [1] NA
NaN == NaN
#> [1] NA
```

E o seguinte resultado usando a família `is`:

```
is.na(NA)
#> [1] TRUE
is.nan(NaN)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Observe que, apesar de `Inf` também poder ser testado com `==`, ele também tem uma função `is`.

```
Inf == Inf
#> [1] TRUE
is.infinite(Inf)
#> [1] TRUE
is.finite(Inf)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Assim teríamos,

```
dados <- data.frame(var = c(32, Inf, NaN, NA))
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  mutate(sem_na = ifelse(is.na(var), 0, var),
         sem_nan = ifelse(is.nan(var), 0, var),
         sem_inf = ifelse(is.infinite(var), 0, var))

#>   var sem_na sem_nan sem_inf
#> 1  32     32      32      32
#> 2 Inf    Inf     Inf       0
#> 3 NaN      0       0     NaN
#> 4  NA      0      NA      NA
```

Atenção porque `NaN` é `NA`, mas `NA` não é `NaN`.